# Get count of documents for sharepoint Site collection using powershell and export to a csv file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I have tried with below script but it is not working,please share the script,if you have any idea.

```
[Void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") 

Start-SPAssignment -Global 

　

$starttime = Get-Date 


$siteurl = Read-Host "Site URL"; 

$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteurl)

　

$webs = $site.Allwebs

$systemlibs =@("Converted Forms", "Customized Reports", "Documents", "Form Templates", 

"Images", "List Template Gallery", "Master Page Gallery", "Pages", 

"Reporting Templates", "Site Assets", "Site Collection Documents", 

"Site Collection Images", "Site Pages", "Solution Gallery", 

"Style Library", "Theme Gallery", "Web Part Gallery", "wfpub")

　

Write-Host "Total number of webs that will be traversed: " $webs.count

　

$DocLibsCount = 0 

$DocLibwItems = 0 

$totalitems = 0 

$subfolderitems = 0

$docLibTitle = ""

　

foreach($web in $webs) 

{ 

$listcoll = $web.lists 



foreach($list in $listcoll) 

{ 

if($list -eq $null) 

{ 

Write-Host 

} 

else 

{ 

$base = $list.GetType() 

if($base.name -eq "SPDocumentLibrary") 

{ 

if ($systemlibs -contains $list) 

{ continue} 

else 

{ 

$docLibTitle = $docLibTitle + " | " + $web.url + " : " + $list.Title



$DocLibsCount += 1 

$items = $list.items 



if($items -ne "0") 

{ 

$DocLibwItems += 1 

#Write-Host "Processing ItemCount for DobLib " $DocLibsCount -ForegroundColor Red 

$totalitems += $items.count 



$name = $list.Title 

$folders = $web.GetFolder($name).SubFolders 

for($etr = 0;$etr -lt $folders.count; $etr++) 

{ 

if($folders[$etr].Name -ne "Forms") 

{ 

#Write-Host "Processing SubFolder ItemCount" -ForegroundColor Red 

$tempcount = $folders[$etr].ItemCount 

$subfolderitems += $tempcount 

} 

} 

} 

} 

} 

} 

} 

} 



Write-Host 

Write-Host 

$str1="URL : " + $siteurl    + "`r`n"

Write-Host "URL : " + $siteurl -ForegroundColor Green 

$str1 = $str1 + "Total # of Document Libraries: " + $DocLibsCount + "`r`n"

Write-Host "Total # of Document Libraries: " $DocLibsCount -ForegroundColor Green 

$str1 = $str1 + "Total # of Document Libraries that contain items: " + $DocLibwItems + "`r`n"

Write-Host "Total # of Document Libraries that contain items: " $DocLibwItems -ForegroundColor Green 

$str1 = $str1 + "Total # of items: " + $totalitems + "`r`n"

Write-Host "Total # of items: " $totalitems -ForegroundColor Green 

$str1 = $str1 + "Total # of items in DocLib\Subfolders: " + $subfolderitems + "`r`n"

Write-Host "Total # of items in DocLib\Subfolders: " $subfolderitems -ForegroundColor Green 

$str1 = $str1 + "List of Document Libraries: " + $docLibTitle + "`r`n"

Write-Host "List of Document Libraries: " $docLibTitle -ForegroundColor Green 

$str1=$str1+"`r`n"

$str1 >> sitedetails.txt

$finishtime = Get-Date 

Write-Host 

Write-Host "Script Duration" –ForegroundColor Yellow 

Write-Host "Started: " $starttime –ForegroundColor Yellow 

Write-Host "Finished: " $finishtime –ForegroundColor Yellow

　

Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```

Comment: "but it is not working"... No output? Error messages? Wrong counts? What's not working?

Comment: Indeed, if you want some help you need to explain the issue better

Answer (score 3):

There is a demo to get count of documents in SharePoint site collection.

```
$NumberOfDoc=0;
$sitecollection=Get-SPSite 'http://sp:5872/'

 $webs= $sitecollection.AllWebs 

      foreach($site in $webs )    
       {    
           foreach($list in $site.Lists)    
          {    
              if($list.BaseTemplate -eq "DocumentLibrary")    
                {    


                      $NumberOfDoc= $NumberOfDoc+$list.ItemCount; #Number item present in document library  

                    Write-Host "Number of Document present in" $list.Title" :" $list.ItemCount;

                  }  

            }  
         } 

 $ScriptFiles="Number of Document in the site colelction"+$NumberOfDoc
Write-Host $ScriptFiles 
 Out-File -FilePath c:\test\test2.csv -InputObject $ScriptFiles -Encoding ASCII -Width 100
```

And you also can refer to the article to get the detail report of all documents in SharePoint site.

[Get detail report of all Documents in SharePoint site using Powershell.](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Get-detail-report-of-all-b29ea8e2)